# CDate Type dismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA. I want to compare timeNow with meetingEnds, that I'll get out of the compounded cell. But I get a type dismatch error. :-(

```
Sub Modul1()
    timeNow = CDate(Time)

    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim cell As String

    For rowCount = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 2
        cell = "C" & rowCount
        meetingEnds = CDate(['cell'])

        If timeNow > meetingEnds Then
            Rows(rowCount).Hidden = True
            Rows(rowCount + 1).Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rowCount
End Sub
```

Is there a way to realise what I wanted to with with

```
meetingEnds = CDate(['cell'])
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where are your definitions/declarations for `meetingEnds`? Why is Cell declared as String?

Comment: Because I have actually no idea what I'm doing, that's why I said I'm new to VBA. :(

Comment: Just a quick look, but use double quotes around "Cell" - a single quote is seen as the beginning of a comment, so that will give you an error right away. As PaulFrancis is implying, declare Cell as a Date. I also would not use Cell as a variable, it will be confusing to read your code later, since ActiveCell is use by Excel VBA.

Comment: Does column C just have a list of times?

Comment: see my loop examples 
[link](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
meetingEnds = CDate(['cell'])
```

to

```
meetingEnds = CDate(ActiveSheet.Range(cell))
```

The reason being, you are storing `Cell` as a string - C1, C3, C5 etc. Any such references should be enclosed or passed as a parameter to the `Range()` method.